# How To Parse Nested API JSON Files

Tags: python, pandas, api

I'm trying to extract pieces of data from this API and have been having difficulties understanding how to do so and go about this. My end goal is to display the different carbon intensity outputs for the region of England in a piechart for each fuel type listed in the data. Since the data is so nested ive been having trouble accessing specific key values and understanding how to sort and extract specific parts, specifically the "generationmix" key values. Ive tried displaying my data using python pandas using the code below but it wont display the "generationmix" section and overall the table looks incomplete. Ive looked up that to parse nested data for JSON data one can use the pandas json_normalize() function. For this, I don't understand any of the values that go along with the function such as "record-path" or "meta".

Here is the link to the data I'm using and the code I've already tried.

Data:
https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional/england

My code:

```
import requests
import pprint
import pandas as pd
import numpy

filename = ("https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional/england")
r = requests.get(filename)
#print("Status Code:", r.status_code)


#Store API responce in a variable
responce_dict = r.json()
#print(responce_dict)

#Normalizing Data
multiple_level_data = pd.json_normalize(responce_dict, record_path = ["data"])
print(multiple_level_data)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you post the DataFrame you want to create?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if json_normalize can help you with this type of json response, but here is how I would do it (ok you can optimize the `flatten` function but you get the idea

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional/england')

if not str(response.status_code).startswith('2'):
    print(f'Status code {response.status_code}, exiting')

response_data = response.json()

def flatten(d, sep='.'):
    cols = [
        'regionid', 'dnoregion', 'shortname',
        'from', 'to', 'intensity.forecast',
        'intensity.index', 'generationmix.fuel',
        'generationmix.perc'
    ]
    items = []
    for city in d.get('data', []):
        item_data = [
            city.get('regionid'), city.get('dnoregion'), city.get('shortname'),
            None, None, None, None, None, None
        ]
        city_items = []
        for city_data in city.get('data', []):
            item_data_tmp = item_data.copy()
            item_data_tmp[3] = city_data.get('from')
            item_data_tmp[4] = city_data.get('to')
            item_data_tmp[5] = city_data.get('intensity', {}).get('forecast')
            item_data_tmp[6] = city_data.get('intensity', {}).get('index')
            for generationmix in city_data.get('generationmix', []):
                item_data_tmp2 = item_data_tmp.copy()
                item_data_tmp2[7] = generationmix.get('fuel')
                item_data_tmp2[8] = generationmix.get('perc')
                city_items.append(item_data_tmp2)
            city_items = city_items or [item_data_tmp]
        items.extend(city_items or [item_data])
    return cols, items


cols, values = flatten(response_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols)
print(df)
```

Which prints

```
   regionid dnoregion shortname               from                 to  intensity.forecast intensity.index generationmix.fuel  generationmix.perc
0        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low            biomass                 6.3
1        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low               coal                 0.9
2        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low            imports                17.2
3        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low                gas                30.6
4        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low            nuclear                10.2
5        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low              other                 0.0
6        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low              hydro                 0.3
7        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low              solar                11.0
8        15   England   England  2021-08-16T15:30Z  2021-08-16T16:00Z                 152             low               wind                23.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This presupposes that the lists only ever contain one element and that the keys always exist. Should give you a clue as to how to manage this:-

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional/england')
    r.raise_for_status()
    j = r.json()
    for d in j['data'][0]['data'][0]['generationmix']:
        print(d)
```

The output of this will be:-

{'fuel': 'biomass', 'perc': 6.3}
{'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0.9}
{'fuel': 'imports', 'perc': 17.2}
{'fuel': 'gas', 'perc': 30.6}
{'fuel': 'nuclear', 'perc': 10.2}
{'fuel': 'other', 'perc': 0}
{'fuel': 'hydro', 'perc': 0.3}
{'fuel': 'solar', 'perc': 11}
{'fuel': 'wind', 'perc': 23.5}